# UICollectionView loads more cells other than visible ones

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView, which has 2k+ records. At anytime only 6-7 rows will be visible and I'm using reusable cells. Everything works fine.

But when I make a console log in cellForRowAtIndexPath, initially 80+ rows are being loaded. After that it loads 1st 7 rows again, and properly loads only the visible cells.

Why does it load 80+ rows initially. This make a slight lag in initial loading.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    print("Cell For Row -> \(indexPath)")

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ResultCell", for: indexPath) as! ResultCell
    cell.data = result[indexPath.item]
    return cell    
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I was using auto-sizing cells. So I did define **estimatedItemSize** as **UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize**

I tried defining a proper **CGSize** instead of UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize. And the extra cells stopped loading.

Comment: It's strange. Can you create a demo project and give me the link?

Comment: Are you using `prefetchDataSource` ?

Comment: @Jack yes.. i do.. But i removed it and tried. Its still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While performing autosizing cells, we give estimatedItemSize.

On using **UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize** for estimatedItemSize, the collectionview tries to load a countable number of cells (visible and non-visible) and get the estimated size.

If a proper CGSize (estimated) is given, the extra cells(non-visible) would be loaded less. So, the closer your estimated size is, the lesser non-visible cells are loaded.